# How to show more element of number picker list in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, numberpicker

I used [this](https://pub.dev/packages/numberpicker) for developing a number picker for my flutter application but it shows only three element of list of numbers in number picker . I want to show more element(for example 7) and beside, I want the selected element be exactly the middle element (in my case 3 element before and three after) which part of the library code should be changed?

When just changing "_listViewHeight = 3 * itemExtent", in library we see the problem I mentioned in image below. First the selected Item is not the middle one beside the maximum value can not be selected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and was able to get it working for odd display number lengths of 3 or greater after digging into the numberpicker code and making some changes. [Here is a diff of the changes I made](https://github.com/alexbhandari/NumberPicker/commit/4535e35269f88b3ba331ce7249a7abd3bbcfb2fc). This is working for me using my [repo](https://github.com/alexbhandari/NumberPicker). You can also just copy the `lib/numberpicker.dart` file from my repo into your project and include that file. Hopefully will get this pulled into the numberpicker project at some point. Below is my example use for 7 numbers displayed at a time:

```
NumberPicker.horizontal(
    initialValue: _currentValue,
    minValue: 1,
    maxValue: 10,
    numberToDisplay: 7,
    onChanged: (newValue) =>
        setState(() => _currentValue = newValue));
```

[image]

and scrolled to the first number

[image]

you can pick a different odd number for the `numberToDisplay` parameter such as 5

[image]

and removing the parameter will use the default of 3.

[image]

More info [here](https://github.com/MarcinusX/NumberPicker/issues/68)

Answer (score 0):

At [here](https://github.com/MarcinusX/NumberPicker/blob/master/lib/numberpicker.dart#L45) and [here](https://github.com/MarcinusX/NumberPicker/blob/master/lib/numberpicker.dart#L79)

**Change**

```
  _listViewHeight = 3 * itemExtent,
```

to

```
  _listViewHeight =  noOfElements * itemExtent,
```

where `noOfElements` is the number of elements you want to display.

Comment: I know this but the selected item is still the second one not the middle of the showing list...